# HTTP Range header not giving proper output with Java

Tags: java, sockets, http

I am writing a simple Java code that simply downloads a file from remote server. I am not using much Java classes. I am creating a simple `java.net.Socket` and writing raw `HTTP` code on the output stream as follows:

`Downloader.java`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;




public class Downloader {

    Socket socket;
    InputStream istream;
    Scanner scanner;
    OutputStream ostream;
    PrintWriter writer;

    String request;



    public Downloader() {

        socket = null;
        istream = null;
        scanner = null;
        ostream = null;
        writer = null;  
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            Downloader downloader = new Downloader();
            downloader.initDownload("cdn.mysql.com", 80, "/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.23-osx10.8-x86_64.tar.gz");
            downloader.download();
            downloader.close();
    }



    public void initDownload(String host, int port, String file) throws IOException {
        // Connecting the socket.
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
    
        // Generating the HTTP request
        request  = "GET "+file+" HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        request += "Host: "+host+":"+port+"\r\n";
        request += "User-Agent: \r\n";
        request += "Connection: Close\r\n";
        request += "Range: bytes=0-1000\r\n";   // This line doesn't work properly.
        request += "\r\n";
    }



    public void download() throws IOException {

        ostream = socket.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(ostream);
    
        writer.println(request);
        writer.flush();
    
        read();
    }



    public void read() throws IOException {

        istream = socket.getInputStream();
        scanner = new Scanner(istream);
    
        // Print the HTTP response by the server on the terminal.
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            if(line.length() == 0)  // break out of the loop when we encounter an empty line. i.e., The blank line between HTTP headers and body.
                break;
        }
    
    
        // Print the data in the file "mysql-5.6.23-osx10.8-x86_64.tar.gz"
        FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream("mysql-5.6.23-osx10.8-x86_64.tar.gz", true);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
            fostream.write(scanner.nextLine().getBytes());
        fostream.close();   
    }



    public void close() throws IOException {

        istream.close();
        scanner.close();
        ostream.close();
        writer.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

The code is quiet clear I suppose. I am trying to read a file from the server using plain sockets. The code works fine. The response header from the server is output on the terminal window, while the data is output in the file. But the `Range` header doesn't give proper output.

When I run the code, this is the `HTTP server response` printed:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: Apache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 06:15:42 GMT
ETag: "5f989776b8f8766c7f43c27c1a09c032:1422821798"
Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2015 13:35:54 GMT
Content-Range: bytes 0-1000/176674931  // Looke here. The output is fine here.
Content-Length: 1001
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-tar-gz
```

While the data goes in the file `mysql-5.6.23-osx10.8-x86_64.tar.gz`.

But when I right click the file `mysql-5.6.23-osx10.8-x86_64.tar.gz` to check it's size, it's size is `1,835 bytes` instead of `1,001 bytes`.

Why is this happening? What should I do to overcome it? Please help.

### PS:

1. I don't wish to use any other inbuilt classes. I wish to do it via raw `HTTP`. Thanks in advance.
2. I am using Macbook Pro, Mac OS X Yosemite, 64-bit.

Comment: I don't know what really is going wrong but using Scanner.nextLine on binary data is probably a bad idea because it throws away the line end and thus corrupts the data. And I think using getBytes to is also not the correct way to get the raw data since this does charset conversion. This then might explain the wrong size.

Comment: @Steffen, is there anything wrong with scanner.nextLine().getBytes()?

Comment: Like I said: nextLine throws line end away and getBytes does character set convertions. Both is not what you want if you need to work with binary data.

Comment: So what should I do not? Coz data is coming as a string. Please help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java (but these kind of errors are typical with other languages too). I'm sure that you will find plenty of documentation on handling binary data with Java. Apart from that, you are doing a HTTP/1.1 request but are not prepared to handle a response with Transfer-Encoding chunked.

Comment: Yeah, the data is binary. But isnt it string on the network? Coz when I download an Html document, it works fine.

Comment: String is a Java type. There is nothing like this on a network, only bytes. How these bytes gets interpreted is up to the application.

Comment: Yeah. But this works fine for an html document. Without the getBytes() but. But the same problem persists with this file when getBytes() is ommitted

Comment: HTML is not binary like a tar.gz file is so it might work even if the code is wrong, because it does not trip over the wrong parts.

Comment: Hmmm. Wish you could give me a solution for this.

Comment: To cite myself: I'm not familiar with Java ... I'm sure that you will find plenty of documentation on handling binary data with Java.

Answer (score 0):

Refer- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html. It suggests that it is possible for the server to ignore range requests which is what is happening in your case I suppose.

Comment: If it ignored, why did it send 1835 bytes? It should have sent all  176674931 bytes. No?